# QT Hash tag/link loading in QWebView

Tags: c++, qt, qwebview

I'd like to ask you a question. I'm writting an application in QT Designer and I made a kind of web browser. I have two radio buttons. If the first one is checked - page index.html is loaded normally to my QWebView. I'm using this:

```
string url = sDir + ui->pageComboBox->currentText().toStdString() + ".html";
ui->logView->load(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QDir::cleanPath(QDir::current().absoluteFilePath(QString::fromStdString(url)))));
```

It's working fine.
But I give user a second option of loading page - if the second radio button is checked then it activates a DateEdit and user have to pick a date. Chosen date is stored in QString. Now, I'd like to load the same page scrolled down to this date:

```
string url = sDir + ui->pageComboBox->currentText().toStdString() + ".html" + showAt.toStdString();
ui->logView->load(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QDir::cleanPath(QDir::current().absoluteFilePath(QString::fromStdString(url)))));
```

So, the requested site link is something like this: index.html#29082013. Here it's not working, no site is loaded :( Still have blank page. I added  tags in html file, so for example in Google Chrome it's working fine. What am I doing wrong? Could you help me? Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
QDir::current().absoluteFilePath(QString::fromStdString(url))
```

You are asking `QDir` (that doesn't know what an url is), to get the filepath of the file `index.html#29082013`, which of course doesn't exist.

The solution is to first get the filepath from `index.html`, then get an url from it, and only then add the hash `#29082013`. Try this:

```
QString filename = QString(sDir) + ui->pageComboBox->currentText() + ".html";
QUrl urlWithoutHash = QUrl::fromLocalFile(QDir::current().absoluteFilePath(filename));
ui->logView->load(urlWithoutHash.toString() + showAt);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't think about soo simple thing. Really, thanks again! :D